# Is it possible to put a search filter on dropdown list in yii 1?

Tags: php, search, drop-down-menu, yii

I have a dropdownlist in my form... The content of it came from a different model... Here's my code

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pr_id'); ?>
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'pr_id', CHtml::listData(PatientRecord::model()->findAll(), 'pr_id', 'first_name'), array('empty'=>'Select Patient')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'pr_id'); ?>
```

Suppose that there are a lot of data from that table, I think the user wouldn't be happy scrolling over choices...
is there a way to put in a search filter on the dropdown?
I think it's possible in Yii2 but I'm using Yii1 at the moment for a project so... any suggestions?

Also, is there a way to show both the first_name and last_name on the display of the dropdownlist?

sorry for the beginner question
any help would be highly appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this [Select2 Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/), download the extension and place it under `/protected/extensions` directory.

Just add it in your view, something like:

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'attribute'=>'pr_id',
      'data'=>$model->searchPatient(),//function to provide data
      // or
      //'data'=>CHtml::listData(PatientRecord::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'first_name')
    ); 
?>
```

and in your model:

```
<?php
    public function searchPatient() {
        $data         = array();
        $patientModel = PatientRecord::model()->findAll();
        foreach($patientModel as $patient){
            $data[] = $patient->first_name." ".$patient->last_name;
        }
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

Thats all you need to do, hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks, it's perfect :) how about the display of first name and last name though?

Comment: @anyabythestars just update `$data[]` in the model, check my updated answer